# knative admission webhook: validation failed: Persistent volume claim support is disabled

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pvc, knative, knative-serving

I am trying to deploy service on `eks` with `knative` installed on eks, here eks configured with `fargate-profile`.
I want to mount `efs` to my service for that i have created `StorageClass`,`PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaim` below are the respective yml

**storageclass.yml**

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: my-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
parameters:
  provisioningMode: efs-ap
  fileSystemId: fs-1234
  directoryPerms: "775"
reclaimPolicy: Retain
```

**efs-pv.yml**

```
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: my-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: fs-1234
```

**efs-pvc.yml**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: my-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
```

all the sc, pv and pvc get created successfully

Now I am trying to use `my-pvc` in my Service **my-service.yml** like below

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice
  annotations:
    serving.knative.dev/efs-storage-class: my-sc
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: key
              value: val
          image: image:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /app/data
              name: data
              readOnly: true # warning were given for not setting readOnly=true
      volumes:
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: my-pvc
            readOnly: true
    metadata:
      annotations:
        autoscaling.knative.dev/metric: concurrency
        autoscaling.knative.dev/target: '1'
        autoscaling.knative.dev/minScale: '1'
        autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale: '5'
        autoscaling.knative.dev/scaleDownDelay: 60s
        autoscaling.knative.dev/window: 600s
```

when I try to run following command `kubectl apply -f my-service.yml` it gives validation error, here the complete error

Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "my-service.yml": admission webhook "**validation.webhook.serving.knative.dev**" denied the request: validation failed: **Persistent volume claim support is disabled**, but found persistent volume claim my-pvc:
must not set the field(s): spec.template.spec.volumes[0].persistentVolumeClaim

Error simply means PVC is disabled, in order to use PVC I need to enable PVC.

**But How and where(in configMap?)?**

in In [serving-core.yml](https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.27.0/serving-core.yaml) i found `kubernetes.podspec-persistent-volume-claim: "Disabled"`
which is example.

So I have tried to add configMap (Just guess) with `kubernetes.podspec-persistent-volume-claim` like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: knative-serving
  name: kubernetes.podspec-persistent-volume-claim
data:
  kubernetes.podspec-persistent-volume-claim: enabled
```

But nothing changed only configmap got created, Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to [set the flag in the `config-features` ConfigMap](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/configuration/feature-flags/#configuring-flags).  That ConfigMap should already have one key, named `_example`.  You'll need to add your key above or below the example.  The `_example` key is ignored by Knative, but provides a place for documentation for system administrators.

Comment: It will great if you add example here

Comment: I have already tried with that, but like create with default value as disabled and then tried to update values as enabled like `kubernetes.podspec-persistent-volume-claim: enabled` and `kubernetes.podspec-persistent-volume-write: enabled`. it didn't refelct changes. Then I deleted my `EKS` and instead of create config-features with default values and then update. I simply created `config-features` with default value enabled for both `configmap-keys`.

Comment: This is weird but I''l try to reproduce this scenario and will update the finding in my question itself.

Answer (score 0):

The [E. Anderson answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76015076/292586) is correct: you need to set the flag in the [config-features ConfigMap](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/configuration/feature-flags/#configuring-flags).

**However**, if you installed [Knative Serving by using the Knative Operator](https://knative.dev/docs/install/operator/knative-with-operators/), you'll need to set the config using the specific custom resource. Otherwise the Operator will reconcile and reset your configmap as soon as you edit it.

```
apiVersion: operator.knative.dev/v1beta1
kind: KnativeServing
metadata:
  name: knative-serving
spec:
  config:
    features:
      kubernetes.podspec-persistent-volume-claim: enabled
      kubernetes.podspec-persistent-volume-write: enabled
```